# Concur V3 Api not working for Users

Tags: c#, httpclient, sap-concur

I configured a Concur Sandbox and played around with the api. Since the User api is not supported by the .Net SDK I wrote following code.

Issue is that code for Expenses work (returns 200 with valida result), but code for users returns 401 Unauthorized.

Expenses

```
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
  {
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth", oauthAccessToken);
      httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

      var requestUri = "https://www.concursolutions.com/api/v3.0/expense/receiptimages";
      var respone = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
      if (respone.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
         var result = respone.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         //throw new InvalidUriException(string.Format("Invalid uri: {0}", requestUri));
        }
      }
```

Ideally this should also work as the previous code works,
Users

```
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth", oauthAccessToken);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

                var requestUri = "http://www.concursolutions.com/api/v3.0/common/users?user=user1%40company.net";
                var respone = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
                if (!respone.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //throw new InvalidUriException(string.Format("Invalid uri: {0}", requestUri));
                }
            }
        }
```

I thought it's a permission issue, but I given allowed enough permission.

Here is the Administration->Webservice app configuration,

[image: Summary]

[image: Application Configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that the User Api call needs to be https.